# Execute Methods in Chain based on array of items

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

not even sure how to title this question. Apologies for that in advance.

Basically, I have an array of checked items that looks like this:

```
const checked_items = ['brand', 'frame_gender', 'sku'...];
```

I would like to query a firebase dataset to something like this:

```
db.collection('glasses')
  // .where('brand' , '==' , 'brand')
  // .where('frame_gender' , '==' , 'Male')
  // .where('sku' , 'array-contains' , 'sku-here')
  .get()
  .then( (snapshot) => ...
```

What is the most efficient way to chain these methods based on my array of items? Any tips? If not clear I can clarify further.

Thanks

Comment: Where are the values coming from?

Comment: It's an array of selected checkboxes, so I'd like to filter based on the selected ones. I got access to the data , my issue is to execute the 'where' method in chain based on the amount of items in the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this will help:

```
const filter = [
    { key: 'brand', op: '==', value: 'brand' },
    { key: 'frame_gender', op: '==', value: 'Male' },
    { key: 'sku', op: 'array-contains', value: 'sku-here' },
];
//...
const filteredQuery = filter
  .filter(item=>item.value!==undefined)
  .reduce(
    (query,{key,op,value})=>query.where(key,op,value),
    query
  );
```

Instead of assigning your checkboxes to `checked_items` you could use the value property of filter items (or it's index so you know what value to set when it's checked/unchecked)

Comment: Amazing solution. That is exactly what I was looking for. The answer below is also a good solution but it does not chain the query so I've had to save the previous query to a variable in order to chain it properly. Your solution should be the accepted answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to know both the name of the field you want to query on, and the value that you want to filter on. In the code you've shared you only show the name, but in my answer I'll assume you also have a list of values.

```
const checked_items = ['brand', 'frame_gender', 'sku'];
const checked_values = ['brand', 'Male', 'sku_here'];
```

Now you can loop over the field names, and create a new query for each.

```
var query = db.collection('glasses');
checked_items.forEach(function(field, index) {
    var value = checked_values[index]);
    query = query.where(field, "==", value);
});
query.get().then(...
```

Comment: [Making impossible states impossible](https://youtu.be/IcgmSRJHu_8?t=8m58s) That would better be: `[{key:'brand',value:'brand'},{key:'frame_gender',value:'Male']`

Comment: Agreed that that are *many* better ways to model the data. Mine would be `let filters = { brand: "brand", frame_gender: "Male", sku: "sku_here" }`. But in my answer I chose to not modify the lines of code that were already provided, to make the answer easiest for OP to follow.

Comment: Thank you guys, I think this is the way to go. I've got the values on another array no probs there. However, my query is not filtering ( feels like the 'where' function in the for loop didn't do anything ), but I guess that is another problem to solve since you've given a good solution for my question.